# Complex HTML table not validating: table row "exceeded the column count established by the first row"

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

validator.w3.org is giving me the error:

> A table row was 4 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1).

It looks like this:

```
|1|2.1|2.2    |
| |3.1|3.2|3.3|
| |4.1|4.4|4.5|
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4"> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 2.1 </td>
      <td colspan="2"> 2.2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 3.1 </td>
      <td> 3.2 </td>
      <td> 3.3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 4.1 </td>
      <td> 4.2 </td>
      <td> 4.3 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I simplified the data, the code is from *Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy* by Sir Isaac Newton, obviously he did not understand HTML table rules any better then I do.

Actual Table: http://lightwizzard.com/books/mathematical.philosophy/mathematical.principles.of.natural.philosophy.html#book3.2.68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to combine your two first rows and change rowspan of the first field:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"> 1 </td>
      <td> 2.1 </td>
      <td colspan="2"> 2.2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 3.1 </td>
      <td> 3.2 </td>
      <td> 3.3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 4.1 </td>
      <td> 4.2 </td>
      <td> 4.3 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```